# In time series prediction, is there a way to give forecast to missing time series?

Tags: pandas, time, series, prediction, forecast

So I have this table:

| DATE | col1 | feature1 | feature2 | feature_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | ts1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 2015-01-01 | ts2 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2015-01-01 | ts3 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2015-01-02 | ts1 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2015-01-02 | ts2 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
| 2015-01-02 | ts3 | NA | NA | NA |

And let's suppose that I have 50 time series, where 20 time series are missing. So I have ts1, ts2, .. ts30 time series, which has every data. Howewer, I want to give a prediction for every time series, including the ones that are missing. And the question is, how can I do that, if it's possible?

I've got the following theoretical solution: Cluster the time series somehow, so in that way I will know which time series will be "closer" to an another one. After that, give predictions for all the features in the time series data in the missing time series, using information from the "close" and not missing time series. And after that, give forecast to all the time series.
Howewer, this seems doable at first glance, I think it could get very unnecessarily complex.
I think this problem is more likely related to a statistical approach, like get a sample, and from that sample give prediction for the whole population. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in stats, so every clarification is welcomed!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)